# How to acces azure blob storage through UNC path

Tags: azure, blob

I've created two virtual machines on Window Azure Portal.
Is that possible to access azure blob storage through network shared files (UNC path) between these virtual machines?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This new feature may be of some interest. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx

Looks like you can create a new share that's backed by azure blob and then mount it on give vm's.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://azuredrive.codeplex.com/

It allows you to mount Blob Storage Accounts as Mapped Drives.

Comment: This sounds interesting. But it is not working on Windows 8 or Window Server 2012. DokainMounter tool doesn't support those OS system :(